# image in the database is not getting changed for each list item

Tags: android, database, image, android-listview

I'm saving image and text in a database,for this i have converted image into string and vice versa.
Now i want to show both of these in a list view.
i don't have any problem regarding textview it is different in every list but in imageview the image is always same which i choose from the gallery.
i am sharing my code overhere.
please help
thanx in advance

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arr_getset.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView imgname;
    ImageView img;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=convertView;


      if(convertView==null){

          /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
          v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);

          /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

          vh = new ViewHolder();

        vh.imgname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        vh.img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img1);


         /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
          v.setTag( vh );
      }
      else 
          vh=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();


    vh.imgname.setText(arr_getset.get(position).getImagename());
    vh.img.setImageBitmap(
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));


    return v;
}

public void ReadValue() {
    idb.open();

    Cursor mcursor = idb.imageDetailCursor();

    while (mcursor.moveToNext()) {
        beanClass = new Bean_Class();
        beanClass.setId(mcursor.getInt(0));
        String imgg =   beanClass.setImage(mcursor.getString(1));
        imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(imgg.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        beanClass.setImagename(mcursor.getString(2));
        arr_getset.add(beanClass);
    }
    Log.d("CHECK11", arr_getset.size() + "@@@");

    if (mcursor.isAfterLast()) {
        mcursor.close();
    }

    mcursor.close();
    idb.close();
}
```

}

Comment: The field imageAsBytes will always contain the last item in your cursor, you never add it to your bean_class so it's never added to the array. And then you use this field in getView instead of referring to the relevant item in the array.

Comment: i got your point will you please help me where should i do modifications and by applying what code

Comment: imageAsBytes should be a field in the beanClass and not in the adapter. Treat just like you treat the ID and the imgg string - set it in the bean instance that you're adding to the array, and then in getView() read from the array - Again, just like you do with the string.

Comment: thanx nitzanj ,iam trying your method and i will let you know after running the code.

Comment: thanx a lot buddy you were right your idea worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanx a lot nitzanj you were right here's the solution.

```
      if(convertView==null){

          /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
          v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);

          /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

          vh = new ViewHolder();

        vh.imgname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        vh.img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img1);



         /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
          v.setTag( vh );
      }
      else 
          vh=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

      vh.img.setImageBitmap(image.get(position));

    vh.imgname.setText(arr_getset.get(position).getImagename());


    return v;
}

public List<Bitmap> ReadValue() {
    image = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    idb.open();

    Cursor mcursor = idb.imageDetailCursor();

    while (mcursor.moveToNext()) {
        beanClass = new Bean_Class();
        beanClass.setId(mcursor.getInt(0));
        String imgg =   beanClass.setImage(mcursor.getString(1));
        imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(imgg.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap im=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
        image.add(im);
        beanClass.setImagename(mcursor.getString(2));
        arr_getset.add(beanClass);
    }
    Log.d("CHECK11", arr_getset.size() + "@@@");

    if (mcursor.isAfterLast()) {
        mcursor.close();
    }

    mcursor.close();
    idb.close();
    return image;
}
```